# How to detect if a notify icon Double clicked

Tags: c#

How to detect if the notify icon get Double clicked

```
private NotifyIcon NotifyIcon;
NotifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
NotifyIcon.Text = "FCleaner";
NotifyIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
NotifyIcon.ContextMenu = cmsNotifyicon;
NotifyIcon.Visible = true;
```

how to call this if the notify icon get double clicked?
     private void NotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

Comment: Attach the MouseDoubleClick event to the function

Comment: I wouldn't call your variable the same name.  Call it `ni` or something.  To attach the handler, use `ni.MouseDoubleClick += ni_MouseDoubleClick;`

Comment: @LarsTech error : The name 'ni' does not exist in the current context

Comment: No kidding.  `private NotifyIcon ni = new NotiftyIcon();`

Comment: @LarsTech error: Object reference not set to an instance of an objec

Comment: How am I supposed to know where you are getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the event, and attach it to your event handler.

```
private NotifyIcon _notifyIcon;

_notifyIcon= new NotifyIcon();
_notifyIcon.Text = "FCleaner";
_notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
_notifyIcon.ContextMenu = cmsNotifyicon;
_notifyIcon.Visible = true;
_notifyIcon.MouseDoubleClick += NotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick;
```